# ASP.NET Core launchSettings.json does not launch browser

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using dotnet core version `2.1.200.`

For my asp.net core application I have following `launchSettings.json` file:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/Contoso.Web.Manager",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64802/",
      "sslPort": 44337
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "dev": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost.manager.contoso.com:5000/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I run `dotnet run --launch-profile dev` this runs application fine in console, but does not open new browser window.

Am I missing something here?

Docs (Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/8487 - I think this is an open issue.

Comment: @AseemGautam thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should use "applicationUrl" instead of "launchUrl" in your dev profile.

```js
"applicationUrl": "http://localhost.manager.contoso.com:5000/",
```

Answer (score 1):

You need applicationUrl and launchUrl, eg:

```json
    "dev": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "/swagger/",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost.manager.contoso.com:5000/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```